# Clip tool gives ERROR 000732?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, clip, error-000732

I am trying to execute clip tool in python on arcGIS 10. 
But it gives error:

> ERROR 000732: Output Extent: Dataset
>   D:/Work/Map/SampleGdb/Sample_02.gdb/Sample_02.gdb/Subcatchments does
>   not exist or is not supported

My code is here:

```
input1 = r"C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tempQYJBTS\tempQYJBTS.gdb\IntRaster"
clipG1 = r"D:/Work/Map/SampleGdb/Sample_02.gdb/Sample_02.gdb/Subcatchments"
outRaster1 = "D:/Temp/ClipTest/clip1"
arcpy.Clip_management(input1,"#",outRaster1, clipG1, "#", "ClippingGeometry")
```

But, I tried the following , and it works fine:

```
input2 = r"C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tempQYJBTS\tempQYJBTS.gdb\IntRaster"
clipG2 = r"D:/Temp/Sample_G.gdb/Subcatchments"
outRaster2 = "D:/Temp/ClipTest/clip2"
```

what is the problem in my first code sample? Does not Path name contains numeric value? Is it ArcGIS rule?

Comment: This is a common error message so be sure to review http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000732

Comment: So this is FGDB in FGDB where you store subcatchments? Something is terribly wrong with this path

Comment: thanks @ FelixIP ; that was the reason. I have corrected the path like this and it works . 
clipG1 = r"D:/Work/Map/SampleGdb/Gdb/Sample_02.gdb/Subcatchments"

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message gives it away where it says that this pathname does not exist.

> D:/Work/Map/SampleGdb/Sample_02.gdb/Sample_02.gdb/Subcatchments

If you really do have a Sample_02.gdb geodatabase inside a Sample_02.gdb geodatabase, then I am sure that will be upsetting the tool.

Instead of:

```
input1 = r"C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tempQYJBTS\tempQYJBTS.gdb\IntRaster"
clipG1 = r"D:/Work/Map/SampleGdb/Sample_02.gdb/Sample_02.gdb/Subcatchments"
outRaster1 = "D:/Temp/ClipTest/clip1"
```

try:

```
input1 = r"C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tempQYJBTS\tempQYJBTS.gdb\IntRaster"
clipG1 = "D:/Work/Map/SampleGdb/Sample_02.gdb/Subcatchments"
outRaster1 = "D:/Temp/ClipTest/clip1"
```

You only need to put `r` in front of pathnames with single backslashes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But same error gives. I have tried your code.

Comment: @Monir Check the path of clipG1. Do you have a feature class at that path? That's all this issue is. We can only guess as to what your actual path is.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have corrected the path like this and it works . clipG1 = r"D:/Work/Map/SampleGdb/Gdb/Sample_02.gdb/Subcatchments"

Comment: Excellent - if you take the `r` away from this one then I bet it will still work.